# Under Ubuntu 12.04,How can I find a window and make it active and click a mouse and input some in it

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium

Under `Ubuntu 12.04`,How can I find a window and make it active and click a mouse and input some in it.

I do an auto-test for a web page with webdriver(http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

A web page has a swfuploader which will invoke a window for uploading file(As we know,the window is outside the browser. I mean the operation in this window can't be done by webdriver if you have some experience under webdriver)

Under the windows, I use autoit(http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to record the operation into a script and use the script through way like 
`"Runtime.exec("c://my_upload.exe")` under java.

The script covers

1.find the upload window( the script can locate the window by title or name )

2.input the file opertion such as "c:\foo\foo.jpg"

3.click the ok button

I want to do the same under the Ubuntu 12.04.

Through the stackflow searching, I got the `python-xlib` ,`python-dogtail` ,`python-pymouse` etc.

But I fail to find how to locate the upload window by using those packages.
(They may have the ability and I may fail to find it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu (or any form of Unix) you can use xdotool (http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/). This can find a window and make it active. If you are using Python, you can call this as a subprocess:

subprocess.Popen('xdotool search --class *windowtype*')

You will need to import subprocess. You can concatenate rules so that you can also locate the button you require to be pressed and send the command, or alternatively, if there is a short cut key this can be pressed, for example, the addition of pressing the "key r" in the window would be:

subprocess.Popen('xdotool search --class *windowtype* key r')

I hope this helps.